# List all IRegistrations in WindsorContainer/Kernel

Tags: castle-windsor, registration, microkernel

How do I get a list of all IRegistrations/ComponentRegistrations in my WindsorContainer or its kernel? I can see a way of doing this by wiring to the ComponentRegistered event and tracking there, but is there an eaiser way?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to list the components?

Comment: To add interceptors to specific components after the fact.

Comment: take a look at IModelInterceptorSelector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the *handlers* from the container, but not the IRegistrations:

```
IHandler[] handlers = container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object));
```

Handlers are basically the registered components. IHandler.ComponentModel contains most of the information of a registered component.

Comment: This will give you all handlers for all services registered in the container. If for some reason you are interested in components you have to create a set out of handler's `ComponentModel` properties.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "create a set out of handler's ComponentModel properties."? Thanks.

Comment: @jeffn825: `container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object)).Select(h => h.ComponentModel)`