# How do you configure Castle Windsor error handling during the creation of components?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

I have a component registered with Castle Windsor which depends on a list of components, each of which is represented by an interface. Castle Windsor is configured similar to the code below.

```
public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        //Allow the container to resolve all IFooComponent 
        //as IEnumerable<IFooComponent>
        container.Kernel.Resolver
           .AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel, false));

        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IMainService>()
                .ImplementedBy<AwesomeMainService>());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IFooComponent>()
                .ImplementedBy<CoolFooComponent>()
                .Named(typeof (CoolFooComponent).Name),
            Component.For<IFooComponent>()
                .ImplementedBy<FooComponentWithUnresolvedDependancy>()
                .Named(typeof (FooComponentWithUnresolvedDependancy).Name)
            //....
        );
    }
}
```

`AwesomeMainService` depends on an `IEnumerable<IFooComponent>` like below

```
public class AwesomeMainService : IMainService
{
    public AwesomeMainService(IEnumerable<IFooComponent> fooComponents) 
    { 
        //I could count the fooComponents here but this is a hack
    }
}
```

Now if one of the `IFooComponent`s is missing a dependency, or Castle Windsor otherwise encounters an exception while instantiating an `IFooComponent`, the exception is caught by Castle Windsor and not rethrown. When I resolve the registered instance of `IMainService` everything appears fine because there is at least on instance of `IFooComponent` which can be created.

```
//No exception here because there is at least 1 IFooComponent
var plugin = _container.Resolve<IMainService>();
```

How do I handle this error and shut everything down? I would've thought there would be an [event on the Kernel](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Container-Events.ashx), but there doesn't appear to be.

**My Fix:**

I created a dynamic parameter for `AwesomeMainService` which counted the number of `IFooProcessor`s registered. The `AwesomeMainService` then verified that this matched the number of `IFooProcessor`s provided.

```
public class AwesomeMainService : IMainService
{
    public AwesomeMainService(IEnumerable<IFooComponent> fooComponents, 
                              int expectedProcessorCount)
    { 
        Verify.That(fooComponents.Count == expectedProcessorCount, 
                    "requestProcessors does not match the expected number " +
                    "of processors provided");
    }
}
```

Then I added this to the AwesomeMainService registration:

```
.DynamicParameters((kernel, parameters) =>
    {
        parameters["expectedProcessorCount"] =
            container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof (object))
                .Where(
                    h => h.ComponentModel.Service.UnderlyingSystemType ==
                         typeof (IRequestProcessor))
                .Count();
    }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation in Windsor 2.5 and earlier. This scenario will fail-fast in Windsor 3.

In v3 there's also a new event `EmptyCollectionResolving` which is raised when a component depends on a collection of `IFoo`s but no component for `IFoo` is registered in the container.

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping you would find my question. Unfortunately I'm not sure I can jump to the beta for this project yet. In the meantime and as a workaround, is there some way I can count the number of `IFooComponent`s which are configured in the Container or Kernel in order to provide this value as a `DynamicParameter` to the ctor of `AwesomeMainService`? Is this what I will need to do to get the components? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951989/list-all-iregistrations-in-windsorcontainer-kernel

Comment: Counting `IFooComponent`s cont: I suppose I could also use the `ComponentRegistered` event to count these. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah one of the events (probably `ComponentModelCreated`) is a good place to hook up and then have a test that resolves the component depending on the collection making sure it gets all the dependencies you need.